# creating virtual directory for existing Dnn website

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have created virtual directory for my DNN website. I want to know how can I use new database for virtual directory and how can i deploy existing code on virtual directory .If any one have idea please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: You are going to want to clarify your question. Are you creating a virtualdirectory/application to run a NEW DNN website, or are you creating a new directory within an existing DNN website? 

What "new database" are you referring to, if you're doing a new install of DNN you will need a new database. 

What "existing code" do you want to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

You can just utilise the virtual directory set up, just like you are setting it up a normal site on IIS. There shouldtn really be any difference from DNNs perspective...

When you say 'deploy existing code', do you mean modules? if yes, then you could just reinstall modules on the installed site again.